# Modals and Verbs for obligations and advice

Tags: difference, modal-verbs

***must***, ***should***, ***need***, ***have to***,  and ***have got to***

Are all these sentences correct to say?

- We **must** work to earn money.
- We **should** work to earn money.
- We **need to** work to earn money.
- We **have to** work to earn money.
- We **have got to** work to earn money.

Comment: Those are all idiomatic, expressing degrees of obligation and necessity. With the **have|need** + infinitive forms, you can express a wider range of temporal scenarios. The modals can also be combined with **have** and **need**. e.g. *We shall have had to work diligently.*

Comment: *We shall have had to work diligently* - i can't understand this one!

Comment: Or even *We should have had to work diligently*.

Comment: It is **shall** or **should** coupled with the helper/auxiliary verb **have** coupled with the finite/tensed verb **have** (had).

Comment: @TRomano I'm still not understanding, God help me out here!!!

Comment: I can come back later, off to work now. But why not ask a separate question about "shall have had to" and "should have had to" and I'm sure others will answer.

Comment: @TRomano Okay. I will. I surely will, my friend.

Comment: "We shall have had to work diligently" = "We did not know why we have had to work diligently, but X makes us conclude this was the case." - X would be inferred from context or described in another sentence.

Comment: Please, somebody, give an answer!