# Shall have had to/Should have had to

Tags: meaning, difference, modal-verbs

[Here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/111057/modals-and-verbs-for-obligations-and-advice?noredirect=1#comment223085_111057) a user [TRomano](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/10264/tromano) gave me advice to ask this question that I don't understand.

> I can come back later, off to work now. But why not ask a separate
>   question about "shall have had to" and "should have had to" and I'm
>   sure others will answer.

What do *"Shall have had to"* and *"Should have had to"* mean?

- We should have had to work diligently.
- We shall have had to work diligently.

Comment: @mike You gotta be kidding?

Comment: apologies - I misread the question as being a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since no answers have been forthcoming, perhaps these examples will show you the meaning.

> I decided not to compete for a place on England's Olympic swimming team. Had I
>   done so, I should have had to work diligently on my freestyle stroke.
>
> If we manage to win this contract, we shall have had to work very diligently to convince the customer of the merits of our product.

Comment: So the first is like: If i were to compete i would need to work diligently. And second is the same but in the Present tense.

Comment: The first is "if I had decided to compete".  It refers to an action in the past that did not take place. So, if I *were to have competed*.... And the second is forward-looking (if we manage to win), and projects the point of view into the future looking back upon the hard work that will have been necessary.

Comment: Okay, now I guess i understand, i think I do.